# Why do Grails command objects commit changes to domain objects by default?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

If I use a GORM domain object in my Grails command object, the command object commits changes to the domain object automatically, even though I did not call the save() method.

I want to bind to GORM objects in the command object but without saving or committing changes to the database. If my controller or my service throw an exception, I want transaction rollback.

I can force the behavior I want with the following annotations, but that feels like I'm doing it the hard way.

```
Controller Class = @Transactional(readOnly = true)
Controller action method = @Transactional
Command Object Class = @Transactional(readOnly = true)
Service Class = @Transactional
```

Am I doing something wrong, are Grails domain objects supposed to get committed automatically by the command object unless I add all these annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to command objects, it's a general feature of controller actions. By default the open-session-in-view pattern is active, where a Hibernate Session is created and bound to a thread-local before the action runs and it's flushed and closed after the action finishes. Any persistent instances retrieved from the database (either explicitly because of a query, or implicitly during data binding) will stay attached to the open session and are dirty-checked when the session flushes. Any modified instances will have their changes flushed along with other queued actions with or without a `save()` call.

Making the entire method (or class) transactional and read-only is probably overkill. A more direct approach would be to either retrieve instances as read-only, e.g. using `read()` instead of `get()`, calling the `readOnly` method when doing criteria queries, etc., or 'detaching' modified instances by calling the `discard()` method on each. Another option is to clear the session at the end of the action so there's nothing to automatically flush, e.g.

```
AnyDomainClass.withSession { it.clear() }
```

Note that instances retrieved in 'read-only' mode can have their changes persisted, but Hibernate won't automatically do anything for those instances, it only happens when you explicitly call `save()`.

Comment: But what I'm seeing is that objects bound in the command object implicitly get committed after the command object and before the first line of the controller action, not at the end of the action. Unless I annotate as above, I seem to get one transaction in the command object and another transaction in the action.

Comment: Can you create a small test app that demonstrates this? I'd like to take a look, so if you could put something working on Github or some other online repo, or even zip up the code and email it to me I could hopefully track this down. If it's a real bug it'd be good to get it reported.

Comment: OK, found it! The demo app didn't have the same behavior. It turns out we were causing the issue by injecting a UtilService into the command object to help with validation. That service was **not** annotated `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, so using it began a transaction and returning to the controller action committed that transaction. Annotating the UtilService `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` fixed the problem.